# Screen odd after quick sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, screen

If I close the lid (suspend) my DELL Inspiron 1545 (Ubuntu 18.04) and immediately open the lid again, the part of the screen bellow the mouse pointer flashes and is all the same colour. The area affected changes as I move the mouse.

After a reboot, the desktop icons are under the favourites. A complete power-off (i.e. remove battery) fixes things.

Probably the best answer will be don't do it! But I am puzzled.

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see what your system does when you suspend/resume.  Especially inspect `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/{98video-quirk-db-handler,99video}`

Answer (score 0):

I have same.

I wrote a `./restart.sh` script,

```
gnome-shell --replace & disown
```

until the issue is fixed.

Comment: Good idea! The `r` GNOME Shell command is simpler and likely achieves the same. (Press Alt+F2 to open the GNOME Shell command-line, enter `r` and press RETURN).